# Github Actions started to fail with node pre-gyp error, Vue app

Tags: node.js, vue.js, github, npm, github-actions

Today, I created a PR on GitHub, but my Actions started to fail with the following:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/runner/work/solid-polls/solid-polls/client/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --update-binary
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/home/runner/work/solid-polls/solid-polls/client/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/home/runner/work/solid-polls/solid-polls/client/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.10
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@18.14.2 | linux | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.3/canvas-v2.9.3-node-v108-linux-glibc-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.3/canvas-v2.9.3-node-v108-linux-glibc-x64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.9.3 and node@18.14.2 (node-v108 ABI, glibc) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.9.3/canvas-v2.9.3-node-v108-linux-glibc-x64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.14.2 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.14.2 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.10.6 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.14.2/node-v18.14.2-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.14.2/node-v18.14.2-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.14.2/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.14.2/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/runner/work/solid-polls/solid-polls/client/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/18.14.2/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/18.14.2',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/runner/.cache/node-gyp/18.14.2/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/home/runner/work/solid-polls/solid-polls/client/node_modules/canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Package pangocairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `pangocairo.pc'
npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
npm ERR! No package 'pangocairo' found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pangocairo --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:325:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.0-10[33](https://github.com/Dtabisolutions/solid-polls/actions/runs/4337222211/jobs/7573072720#step:4:34)-azure
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary" "--module=/home/runner/work/solid-polls/solid-polls/client/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/home/runner/work/solid-polls/solid-polls/client/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v108"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /home/runner/work/solid-polls/solid-polls/client/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.14.2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --update-binary --module=/home/runner/work/solid-polls/solid-polls/client/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/home/runner/work/solid-polls/solid-polls/client/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v108' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/solid-polls/solid-polls/client/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1091:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.0-1033-azure
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/home/runner/work/solid-polls/solid-polls/client/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--update-binary"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /home/runner/work/solid-polls/solid-polls/client/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v18.14.2
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.10
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/runner/.npm/_logs/2023-03-05T17_[38](https://github.com/Dtabisolutions/solid-polls/actions/runs/4337222211/jobs/7573072720#step:4:39)_[45](https://github.com/Dtabisolutions/solid-polls/actions/runs/4337222211/jobs/7573072720#step:4:46)_7[61](https://github.com/Dtabisolutions/solid-polls/actions/runs/4337222211/jobs/7573072720#step:4:62)Z-debug-0.log
make: *** [Makefile:15: build-client] Error 1
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

The strange part is that I did not have made any changes from the previous PR, which successfully finished the actions. I have not installed any new npm packages or something like that, but just added some more functionalities in my app. Additionally, the same command that is ran on the GitHub Actions is successfully passing locally.

I will be very happy if someone can help me to solve this issue, cause I just cannot find an answer/solution.

Here is my yml:

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions
name: CI

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on pull request events but only for the master branch
  pull_request:
    branches: [develop]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16.x]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/
    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build the API
        run: make build-api
      - name: Build the Admin UI
        run: make build-client
      - name: Build the Mobile App UI
        run: make build-mobile
```

It fails on `make-build-client`, which contains the following commands:

`rm -rf ./dist/admin-ui && cd ./client && npm ci --legacy-peer-deps && npm run build`

Comment: gyp errors mean that a combo of node and platform is not normal so binary deps had to be compiled and failed. Here it can be seen that Node is 18 for some reason, while you expect 16.

Comment: While you're at it, this is quite the anti-pattern right here. You want to separate each command into it's own step, to make the pipeline more transparent. So consider creating steps like:
1. Clean dist folder (in GHA, you should always start with a clean env, so this is not even necessary)
2. Install Dependencies (npm ci stuff)
3. Building App (npm run)
etc.

Comment: @EstusFlask How this can be fixed? I also noticed this, but not sure why it is like that and how to solve the problem.

@Hegi, so, you suggest to separate the whole `make-build-client` command into separate steps, am I correct? If so, it will be better to have separate .yml file for each api, client and mobile, right?

Comment: I don't use GA much while the problem is very specific to it. Since this broke at once this looks like some bug or deprecation on GH side. Notice that it's documented `node` and not `node-version` in the matrix, https://github.com/marketplace/actions/setup-node-js-environment#matrix-testing

Comment: @EstusFlask yeah, it looks like that. I will try to set the node-version as they provided in the documentation you've sent. Thanks!

I already configured my docker and act https://github.com/nektos/act, in order to run the workflows locally. However, the workflow on the local docker is running fine. So, I also came to conclusion that it might be an issue from GHA.

Comment: @EstusFlask it works by manually setting the node, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing the workflow file to setup the node version based on the matrix and I also changed the `16.x -> 16`. Here is the updated file:

```
# This is a basic workflow to help you get started with Actions
name: CI

# Controls when the workflow will run
on:
  # Triggers the workflow on pull request events but only for the master branch
  pull_request:
    branches: [develop]

  # Allows you to run this workflow manually from the Actions tab
  workflow_dispatch:

# A workflow run is made up of one or more jobs that can run sequentially or in parallel
jobs:
  # This workflow contains a single job called "build"
  build:
    # The type of runner that the job will run on
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [16]
        # See supported Node.js release schedule at https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/
    name: Build with node version ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    # Steps represent a sequence of tasks that will be executed as part of the job
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Setup node
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: Build the API
        run: make build-api
      - name: Build the Admin UI
        run: make build-client
      - name: Build the Mobile App UI
        run: make build-mobile
```

If anyone wants to test the workflows locally and do not how, one can use the [act](https://github.com/nektos/act). Here is also a video how it can be [used](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8TBWRgU-JqI).

Thanks to @EstusFlask for pointing me to that direction!